# Is there a way to locate line from stack trace in Playframework?

Tags: playframework

I'm using Playframework 2.3.9 and having problem that occurs only in Selenium test in Jenkins build.

```
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:0.13.8-M5]
at views.html.showOrderHistory$.apply(showOrderHistory.template.scala:47) ~[classes/:na]
at controllers.OrderHistory$$anonfun$showOrderHistory$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(OrderHistory.scala:70) ~[classes/:na]
```

It shows line number of the code generated by template. Since this occurs only in Selenium test in Jenkins and not in my local PC. I have no clue other than this stack trace.
Is there any way to locate the line of template code using this stack trace information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found generated template code under target/scala-2.11/twirl.